# Issues with Telerik RadEditor toolbar in Chrome

Tags: css, .net, google-chrome, telerik, radeditor

I am having some problems with RadEdtitor toolbar in Chrome browser at the moment (I am using the latest Chrome). I can not seem to apply different font styles, font sizes and colors. After clicking on the buttons, nothing has changed. See below.

[image: Chrome doesn't like font changes]

For other browsers, like Firefox & IE, they are all working fine. Has anyone experienced this issue?

[image: good result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Telerik controls version? If it is not the latest, test it. I think Q3 2013 SP2 is the last one that went out. The first major release for 2014 should be coming soon, too.
If you can break it here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx just report it to them.

Comment: thanks for the tip. The version is 2012.1.411.40, which is kind of outdated. Will consider having it upgraded.